# How to dockerize json-server?

Tags: reactjs, docker, json-server

I'm trying to run json server with docker along with my application in react, but it's not working.

My dockerfile and compose settings:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

---

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    react:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 3000:3000

    json-server:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 4000:4000
        command: npm run server
```

when I run the command docker-compose up, my react application works but the json server shows this in the terminal:

```
frontend@0.0.0 server
json-server --watch ./db/dados.json --port 4000

\{^_^}/ hi!
Loading ./db/dados.json
Done

Resources
http://localhost:4000/encomendas
Home
http://localhost:4000
Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
Watching...
```

And nothing happens when I try to fetch the data.

console output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `--host` flag in your json-server command

`json-server --watch ./db/dados.json --port 4000 --host 0.0.0.0`

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: Can you share the console output ?

Comment: I added a console image

Comment: What URL are you using to fetch the data?

Comment: Thanks @heyitsvajid , the `--host 0.0.0.0` was the missing bit for me :D